# Oracle SQL editor tools

Tags: oracle

OK, I've used TOAD in the past and it's pretty cool, but I don't feel like spending that kind of coin. What other Oracle 10g SQL editors are there?

Note: I don't need tuning tools, simply SQL query tools.

Comment: I currently use SQL*Plus from Oracle. I'd like something that is able to give me previews of data in tables and views, and something that allows me to select code snippets and execute the queries from there.

Comment: Try dbForge Studio for Oracle. It has a powerful [oracle sql editor](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/studio/) tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) is free, Java based, graphical and made by Oracle. BUT it is made by Oracle, which should give you a hint about its overall usability (improving over versions, to be fair).

To be able to connect to Oracle 8i, you will need an old version of this tool (has to do with JDBC support, or rather lack of it). Try 1.2.1.

Comment: So true! I use SQL Developer, and it is so heavy and memory-hungry... I load it, use it and unload it as fast as possible. On my machine it usually takes up about 700MB of RAM :-o

Answer (score 3):

I've always used [TOra](http://tora.sourceforge.net/). Free software (GPL). I've used it on Linux, not sure if it runs on Windows.

They have [screenshots](http://tora.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html) if you're interested.

Comment: Looks like they do have Solaris, Windows, and Linux builds.
http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=16636&package_id=25533&release_id=637973

Answer (score 1):

Sqldeveloper from oracle 
Squirrel SQL, using de oracle jdbc driver.

Answer (score 1):

I agree Oracle SQLDEveloper is pretty good and a great price.  We use it more than Toad now.  Some early gotcha's ...

1. Difference versions still available have different functionality (an earlier version we installed had a T-SQL -> PL/SQL tool, a later version didn't)... so a recent version that has what you need and stick with it.
2. The default font will (or at least did) make a zero 0 and a capital letter O look the same, which we blew hours on once while trying to debug a query.
3. We spent a while trying to set up a connection between our subversion repository and SQL developer, and never really got value from it.

Other than that, we've been happy with it, and it has a nice DDL exporting feature and Diff tool.

Answer (score 0):

Quote:

> [EMS SQL Manager for Oracle](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/oracle/manager) is a high performance database tool for Oracle Database server development and administration. SQL Manager for Oracle works with any Oracle versions from 8.1.7 to the newest one and supports the latest Oracle Database features and data types including compressed, OLAP, read-only and read-write tables; invisible indexes; compound triggers, triggers with FOLLOWS clause and others. It offers plenty of powerful Oracle tools such as PL/SQL Code Debugger, Backup/Restore Database wizards, Visual Database Designer to create Oracle database in few clicks, Visual Query Builder to write complex Oracle SQL queries, Database Statistics to monitor Oracle performance, Grant manager for effective Oracle security management and many more useful features for efficient Oracle administration. SQL Manager for Oracle has a state-of-the-art graphical user interface with a well-described wizard system, so clear in use that even a newbie will not be confused with it.

They also have a freeware version, with some [limitations](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/oracle/manager/matrix).

Answer (score 0):

If your'e doing basic sysadmin queries, just use the standard Oracle SQL*Plus client that comes with a standard install.  No additional cost.

If you need specific features, I'd mention them in your question.

Comment: Good point. I've added the comment to my question stating a little more about what I'm looking for. I currently use SQL*Plus.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Sql Developer has one really cool plugin from FourthElephant called [Insider](http://www.fourthelephant.com/sqldeveloper/download/).  It is a database monitor.  It is a simple version that is free.  (The advanced one you have to pay for.)

The tool that comes with Oracle, Enterprise Manager, is a good approach but doesn't give you the same type of visual cueing.  Give it a try, its free.

SQL Plus is a dinosaur but faily solid as a script executer but not really good for PL/SQL.

One really odd alternative for you developers reading this are the [oracle tools](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/dotnet/tools/index.html) for visual studio.  It has just about everything in it including debugging and is a free add-on for visual studio.  If you are a developer that loves visual studio but is also trying to manage a test database this is a powerful tool.
One thing I really like about it is how it handle reference cursors.  For some reason it is the best tool I have found for testing my reference cursors.